# How inherit the struct in swift?

Tags: swift, inheritance

Is there any to inherit a struct in Swift?

```
struct Resolution {
    var width = 0
    var height = 0
}
struct Display : Resolution {}
```

Comment: No, there's **no** way. It is designed that way. Refer to manual: ["Classes and Structs"](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/ClassesAndStructures.html) and ["Inheritance"](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Inheritance.html)

Comment: Is there a reason you need to inherit? If so, use classes. Else, why not let your supposed inheriting object contain an instance of `Resolution`. That' is called composition btw.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Alternate approach to inheritance for Swift structs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48819953/alternate-approach-to-inheritance-for-swift-structs)

Answer (score 6):

`struct`s can only inherit (if that is the right word) from protocols. The cannot inherit from a base `struct` so you cannot do

```
struct Resolution {
    var width = 0
    var height = 0
}

struct MyStruct: Resolution { ... } // ERROR!
```

So you have two options. The first is to use a `class` instead. The second is to refactor your code to use protocols.

So, if you have some common methods, you might do:

```
protocol PixelContainer
{
   var width: Int { get }
   var height: Int { get }
}

extension PixelContainer
{
    var count: Int { return width * height }
}

struct Resolution: PixelContainer
{
    var width = 10
    var height = 20
}

let numPixels = Resolution().count // Legal
```

Comment: `inherit (if that is the right word) from protocols` — it's called `conforming` in `Swift` (or `implementing` in other languages that have `interfaces` instead of `protocols`).

Comment: @user28434 That's true, but `struct`s can also use methods and properties defined in protocol extensions. That is a sort of inheritance.

Comment: Still not `inheritance`, just `using default implementations`.

Comment: @user28434 It's not a default implementation. The method is not declared in the protocol requirements. It's just an extension method.

Comment: then it has absolutely nothing with `inheritance` at all. Because it's just extension, it doesn't build hierarchy, it just adds behaviour to existing types.